# Suppressing gridlines in ggplot for Python

Tags: python, gridlines, python-ggplot

I would like to create a simple scatter plot using ggplot for Python, but I don't want grid lines in the plot. Is there a way to suppress the gridlines? I know in ggplot2 I can use something like

```
theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

However, I can't find anything similar in the `ggplot` for Python documentation or on StackExchange.

Comment: Does passing `axes_grid=False` to your theme work?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not.

Comment: ggplot for Python is very new and probably doesn't have feature parity yet with gpplot2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I was able to find a theme at http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/theme_matplotlib.html